# Virtual table in llvm (llvm-py)

Tags: python, compiler-construction, llvm, vtable, llvm-ir

I'm using llvm-py to create a DIY compiler for some artificial and need to have a virtual method table in the globe scope. My concept is to  have several arrays of function pointers (one for each class). Unfortunately there's no LLVM IR Builder for a global scope and I cannot use ptrtoint in order to have uniform type of all array elements (otherwise I would store function addresses as 64-bit ints and cast them to appropriate types before calling). Do you know any reasonable solution? It can also be illustrated with C++ LLVM api, because llvm-py is very similar.

Comment: Did you check what Clang emits for C++ vtables?

Comment: Yep, it does some name mangling tricks that make the code pretty hard to understand and I wanted to avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, `IRBuilder` does not expose an interface to do that, but you can create it manually - e.g. by using the constructors of `GlobalVariable`. You can store all the pointers in an array using conversion constant expressions, i.e. by generating:

```
@global = global [4 x i64*] [
  i64* bitcast (void()* @f to i64*),
  i64* bitcast (float(i32)* @g to i64*),
  ...
]
```

So, use `ConstantExpr::getBitCast()` to generate the casts from the `Function` to the array element type (which should preferrably be a pointer, I don't see the advantage in storing an `i64`). Then create a new `GlobalVariable` in the module and initialize it with all the constant expressions you've created.

Comment: All right, I have totally forgotten about this bitcast method available in ConstantExpr. Thanks a lot!